# HTML5/canvas : Bridging together touch events + keydown events for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, canvas, touch

I've been struggling with this issue for the past few days. I'm pretty new to javascript and jQuery and I'm a little bit confused on where to go.

Basically, I made the game, Snake, following a tutorial; on desktops, I'm using the keydown inputs for up, down, left, and right. I am trying to make it so the game is also user and touch friendly on jQuery mobile. I've downloaded a few touch plugins, but I am not sure where to go from there or if it even works.

As part of my game.js file,

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == "37" && d!= "right") d= "left";
    else if (key =="38" && d!= "down" ) d= "up";
    else if (key == "39" && d!="left") d= "right";
    else if (key == "40" && d!="up" ) d=  "down";
```

The problem I'm having now is: how do I make implement the touch inputs so that it also is able to refer back to the keydown inputs? Would I include it in my index.html as inline? Part of game.js file? Or a new file?

Thanks! I'd appreciate any help/guidance!

Comment: What sort of touch input do you plan on using? Will there be 4 directional buttons on screen that the user can tap, or are you planning on responding to directional swipes. etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a hack solution, but it'll certainly work.

1) Move the keydown function out of an anonymous block into a named function that takes and event object as a parameter.

2) make you overlay controls call functions that override the default event object to assign e.which to whatever value the control corresponds to.

So...

This:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == "37" && d!= "right") d= "left";
    else if (key =="38" && d!= "down" ) d= "up";
    else if (key == "39" && d!="left") d= "right";
    else if (key == "40" && d!="up" ) d=  "down";
```

Becomes

```
function handle_keys(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == "37" && d!= "right") d= "left";
    else if (key =="38" && d!= "down" ) d= "up";
    else if (key == "39" && d!="left") d= "right";
    else if (key == "40" && d!="up" ) d=  "down";
}

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  handle_keys(e);
}
```

And for your touch events you would just do

```
$("#left_button").touchstart(function(e){
    e.which = 37;
    handle_keys(e);
})
```